# downloaded a jupyter notebook but it won't open

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

New to learning code: I started an online learning program for Machine Learning and Data Science. I completed the first project linear regression using a Jupyter Notebook  and Python 3 using Anaconda. It was saved as a ipynb file.

I downloaded and saved it on laptop(PC) but now it will not open. I think maybe I need to download something on my laptop that recognizes the notebook application.

Ok thank you to those who responded to my question. File opens from Jupyter Notebook just fine, I was trying to open from document folder. Thanks again!!

Comment: Could you please include the error message in your question?

Comment: pip install notebook

Comment: When you were working with Jupyter, was it on a particular website, such as Binder, Google Colab or Kaggle Kernels? If so, you first need to install the Jupyter server application on your computer following this: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html. Note that you also need to have Python installed.

Comment: No error code. 'Partial download' is next to file so I believe it didn't download correctly. Maybe Jupyter notebook disconnected before download was completed.

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter runs as a webserver on your local machine or a remote machine.
If you want to open a notebook file to run or view it you need the jupyter server application and have to start it to use notebooks in your browser.
https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html

If you want to have support that launches a jupyter server instance based on the file ending you may want to take a look at the Jupyter editor extension e.g. for VS Code (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) or PyCharm that take care of launching and displaying notebooks

Comment: Yeah, In order to run Jupiter notebook, you need to install Anaconda and you can open Jupiter notebook and run that particular file

Comment: @Theepag - Anaconda is not required for Jupyter. Anaconda is simply a wrapper for various analytical tools, including Jupyter.

Comment: Anaconda isn't require but we can use Anaconda!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed it? ;-)

If you’re using a menu shortcut or Anaconda launcher to start it, try opening a terminal or command prompt and running the command jupyter notebook.

If it can’t find jupyter, you may need to configure your PATH environment variable. If you don’t know what that means, and don’t want to find out, just (re)install Anaconda with the default settings, and it should set up PATH correctly.

If Jupyter gives an error that it can’t find notebook, check with pip or conda that the notebook package is installed.

Try running jupyter-notebook (with a hyphen). This should normally be the same as jupyter notebook (with a space), but if there’s any difference, the version with the hyphen is the ‘real’ launcher, and the other one wraps that.